# PHP sort array by key names

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like this

```
//$src
Array(
[dim_55] => path/to/image.jpg
[dim_180] => path/to/image.jpg
[dim_190] => path/to/image.jpg
[dim_475] => path/to/image.jpg
[dim_635] => path/to/image.jpg
[dim_540] => path/to/image.jpg
[dim_1130] => path/to/image.jpg
[dim_1900] => path/to/image.jpg
)
```

( `path/to/image.jpg` is a generic path )

I would like to order this by `key` in an order like

```
dim_1900
dim_1130
dim_635
dim_540
dim_475
..
```

To achieve this solution I did something like:

```
$sortSrc = array();
foreach($src as $key => $value){
  $newkey = explode("dim_", $key);
  $sortSrc[$newkey[1]] = $value; 
}

krsort($sortSrc);
```

It works but maybe is not so effective. Is there a way in which I can achieve this with native `PHP` functions?

Comment: `krsort` is a native php function, or i'm missing something in your question?

Comment: Use the existing sort functions with the `SORT_NATURAL` flag: `krsort($myArray, SORT_NATURAL);`

Comment: with out loop your code works true I think

Comment: @OfirBaruch I was talking about the `foreach`

Comment: Can you please share the structure of `$src`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `krsort($src, SORT_NATURAL);`

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php for sort flags documentation

Comment: It was too early eheh :)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to achieve what you want with ksort:

`krsort — Sort an array by key in reverse order`

```
 <?php
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
krsort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
d = lemon
c = apple
b = banana
a = orange
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use custom sort by key numeric with [`uksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) function, try this code

```
<?php 
$data = Array(
"dim_55" => "path/to/image.jpg",
"dim_180" => "path/to/image.jpg",
"dim_190" => "path/to/image.jpg",
"dim_475" => "path/to/image.jpg",
"dim_635" => "path/to/image.jpg",
"dim_540" => "path/to/image.jpg",
"dim_1130" => "path/to/image.jpg",
"dim_1900" => "path/to/image.jpg"
);
$sort_data = uksort($data, function($a, $b){
  preg_match("/dim_(\d+)/",$a, $matcha);
  preg_match("/dim_(\d+)/",$b, $matchb);
  if($matcha[1] == $matchb[1]){
    return 0;
  }
  return $matcha[1] > $matchb[1] ? -1 : 1;
});
print_r($data);
?>
```

[DEMO](https://eval.in/371759)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$a = [
    'dim_55' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
    'dim_180' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
    'dim_190' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
    'dim_475' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
    'dim_635' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
    'dim_540' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
    'dim_1130' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
    'dim_1900' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
];

krsort($a, SORT_NATURAL);

print_r($a);
```